Error using i18n to translate a Vue with TS project
I'm looking to translate a college project into other languages, so I looked up some ways of doing this and found I18n. I installed it in the root of my project using npm install vue-i18n@10.
I do the import at the top of my file, call the createI18n function and when I use app.use(i18n) it gives the following error:
The argument of type ‘I18n<{}, {}, {}, string, true>’ is not assignable to the parameter of type ‘Plugin<[]>’.
  The type ‘I18n<{}, {}, {}, string, true>’ cannot be assigned to the type ‘{ install: (app: App<any>) => any; }’.
    Property types ‘install’ are incompatible.
      The type ‘(app: App<any>, ...options: unknown[]) => void’ cannot be assigned to the type ‘(app: App<any>) => any’.
        The parameter types ‘app’ and ‘app’ are incompatible.
          The ‘onUnmount’ property is missing in the type ‘import(’c:/Projetos/pibic/Tutor_de_ensino_TS/aplicacao/frontend/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.) App<any>‘, but it is mandatory in the type “import(”c:/Projetos/pibic/Tutor_de_ensino_TS/aplicacao/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core’).App<any>'.ts(2345)
runtime-core.d.ts(1041, 5): ‘onUnmount’ is declared here.
const i18n: I18n<{}, {}, {}, string, true>

I've already tried creating a Vue project from scratch to see if it was a configuration of the current project and yet the same error appeared when I used app.use(i18n)
I'm using these versions of vue:
aplicacao@ C:\Projetos\pibic\Tutor_de_ensino_TS\aplicacao
└─┬ vue-i18n@10.0.3
  └─┬ vue@3.5.10
    └─┬ @vue/server-renderer@3.5.10
      └── vue@3.5.10 deduped


I'd suggest to not use recently released major version (10), exactly because of possible implications like this one, unless you want to be an early adopter. Try to downgrade to 9. If this solves the problem, this is an issue that needs to be reported

It looks like you wrote I18n instead of i18n? This will use the Type and not the module. Another problem could be the createI18n call. Maybe share more of your code especially the import, the createI18n and use part.
Do you import something like this as i18n?
export default createI18n<[MessageSchema], TYPE_AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES>({
  locale: "en",
  fallbackLocale: "en",
  legacy: false,
  messages: {
    en: en,
    de: de,
    fr: fr,
    ar: ar,
  },
});

